# Accessing properties of different types of UserControls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I created a new Windows Forms Control Library and created 2 different user controls.
I imported the controls to my main form on another project and am able to access controls when I create them.

```
UserControlType1 uc1 = new UserControlType1();
UserControlType2 uc2 = new UserControlType2();
```

The controls both have a Status property I can access on the form.
I can access the status from each individually.

```
Debug.Print(uc1.Status);
Debug.Print(uc2.Status);
```

But is there a way I can access that status from an array of different user controls or some other way? I plan on having 2 dozen or more different user controls and would like to reference them by index depending on which tab on the main form is active. I'm new to user controls, what approach should I take?

```
object[] uc_array = new object[2]{uc1, uc2};  // unable to access properties
```

Comment: If all your UserControls have that `Status` property, you can include it in an interface (let's call it "IMyUserControlType"), that all your controls implement. You then can have an array `IMyUserControlType[] UcArray` instead of `object[]`. And all of its elements would have an accessable `Status` property.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a support class inherited by all the different usercontrols. In the main form I created a new array of these types and populated them.

```
UserControlType1 uc1 = new UserControlType1();
UserControlType2 uc2 = new UserControlType2();
Support[] supp_ar = new Support[2]{uc1.Properties, uc2.Properties};

Debug.Print(supp_ar[0].Status);  // does now show the status
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in agreement with Fildor's comment because implementing an `interface` can be quite a bit more flexible and extensible. There's no requirement to inherit any particular base class, and it's possible to mix-and-match interfaces as a form of de facto multiple inheritance. In this case, it might be especially useful to include an `event` so the `UserControl` can notify the parent when something happens that might require a status update.

```
interface IStatusProvider
{
    string Status { get; }
    event EventHandler StatusUpdated;
}
```

---

**Example of a `CustomUserControl : UserControl, IStatusProvider`**

```
class UserControlTypeA : UserControl, IStatusProvider
{
    public UserControlTypeA()
    {
        _checkBox =
            new CheckBox
            {
                Text = "CheckBox",
                Size = new Size(150, 50),
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Appearance = Appearance.Button,
            };
        _checkBox.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) => 
            StatusUpdated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        Controls.Add(_checkBox);
        AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        AutoSize = true;
    }
    private readonly CheckBox _checkBox;

    public event EventHandler StatusUpdated;

    public string Status => $"{GetType().Name}: {_checkBox.Checked}";
}
```

---

The various different `UserControl` types can be instantiated as a collection of `IStatusProvider`:

```
IStatusProvider[] UserControls = new IStatusProvider[]
{
    new UserControlTypeA(),
    new UserControlTypeB(),
    new UserControlTypeC(),
};
```

You can use an [implicit cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) in a `foreach`, for example to use it as a `Control`:

```
// Implicit cast from IStatusProvider to Control
foreach (Control control in UserControls)
{
    flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

Otherwise, the variant in the `foreach` will evaluate to `IStatusProvider` and this is where the different user controls will provide different responses to `Status`:

```
// IStatusProvider
foreach (var statusProvider in UserControls)
{
    statusProvider.StatusUpdated += onAnyStatusUpdated;
}

private void onAnyStatusUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var statusProvider in UserControls)
    {
        textBoxMultiline.AppendText($"{statusProvider.Status}{Environment.NewLine}");
    }
    textBoxMultiline.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

---

The result of iterating the `UserControls` collection is shown here, where the `flowLayoutPanel` is on the left and the status updates are shown on the right.

[image: three user controls]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/istatus-provider.git) this example.